# Getting Null Pointer Exception in ListView setMultiChoiceListener Method Android

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am tying to populate a `listview` with the Object of Class Contact which has the name of the person, phone number and image. I have managed to create one and next thing I need to implement is a 'delete' feature to it by long pressing the item I get to select delete option from the action bar. Everything works fine except when I select the last item on the list, I get a Null Pointer Exception at the `setBackgroundColor(getResources()...)` part. I have included '`try`....`catch`' to the `if` part of the code but still the selection and the deletion operation for the last items on the list is not working.

```
if (checked) {
                try {
                    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkblue));
                    Contact prsntoArray = (Contact) personDlt;
                    dltPersonsList.add(prsntoArray);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light));
                dltPersonsList.remove(personDlt);

            }
```

This is the whole onCreate method for the app.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_contacts_listview);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<Contact> contactList = db.getAllContacts();
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_view_item,contactList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            // Capture total checked items
            final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
            // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            personDlt = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (checked) {
                try {
                    listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkblue));
                    Contact prsntoArray = (Contact) personDlt;
                    dltPersonsList.add(prsntoArray);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light));
                dltPersonsList.remove(personDlt);

            }
            // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
            listAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete:
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = listAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                            Contact selecteditem = listAdapter
                                    .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                            // Remove selected items following the ids
                            listAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                        }
                    }
                    Iterator<Contact> dltIter = dltPersonsList.iterator();
                    do {

                        Contact dltContct = dltIter.next();
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        db.deleteContact(dltContct);

                    } while (dltIter.hasNext());


                    // Close CAB
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            listAdapter.removeSelection();

        }
    });}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added a try block on a single `getChildAt` call.

You should instead just do a null check:

```
if (listView.getChildAt(position) != null) {
    if (checked) {
        listView.getChildAt(position)
                .setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkblue));
        Contact prsntoArray = (Contact) personDlt;
        dltPersonsList.add(prsntoArray);
    } else {
        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light));
        dltPersonsList.remove(personDlt);
    }
}
```

---

Keep in mind that ListView re-uses the view so when scrolled the background may become applied to other items. That is of course if you don't have any specific code in your adapter that manages these states. However this is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Hi Simas, Still I am not able to select the last items in the list. Also if I select the first item in the list then automatically the last item in the list is also getting selected. Is there any issue with the code?